# Help with else/if else in arcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm attempting to create quick code that simply assigns a gps coordinate to a certain station on the map. Here's my current code
Pre-logic script code:

```
def update_nones(lat,bay_statio):
if bay_statio=="apalachicola0":
    return 29.733333
elif bay_statio == "apalachicola1":
    return 29.7583008       
   else:
 return lat
```

lat=

```
update_nones(!lat!,!bay_statio!)
```

For some reason I keep receiving an error in the geo-processing window. The code works with one condition but once I had the elif statement it refuses to compile.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is a pure Python problem, nothing to do with ArcMap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like your indentation is not correct. Try this snippet:

```
def update_nones(lat,bay_statio):
  if bay_statio=="apalachicola0":
    return 29.733333
  elif bay_statio == "apalachicola1":
    return 29.7583008       
  else:
    return lat
```

Comment: That did the trick, I'm still a newb (just learning the ropes to speed up some map making) and I had no idea that indentation was so important!

Comment: If it works, mark answer as correct